# legacy code mean

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does this question mean?

> What do you do when you find legacy code in your team product?

I haven't acknowledged the phrase

> legacy code

before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479596/what-makes-code-legacy

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legacy adjective, definition 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legacy code is a computer science term. It refers to programming code that was written much earlier than other code in the same project or other closely related software.

Legacy code may be necessary in some cases for backward compatibility, but it is problematic to maintain because the people and software tools that created it are probably long gone. This may necessitate recreating the functionality from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.